# How to turn raw data stored in geo-referenced cells into a matrix to create new raster layers?

Tags: r, csv, matrix, split, raster

I have a dataset of animal species assigned to spatial grid cells ("Names of species in each cell.csv"), so each row shows centroid coordinates of each cell (X and Y coordinates) and "names" of animals co-occurring:

```
             X          Y                            names
1 -11674838.48 7245745.48 sp1~sp2~sp3
2 -10324030.56 7245745.48 sp1~sp3~sp6~sp7~sp11
3 -16402680.16 4930074.76 sp3~sp4~sp22~sp23~sp24~sp25~sp29
4 -13958700.56 6457645.24 sp2~sp3~sp6~sp8~sp9~sp10
5 -10484850.56 7839744.11 sp1~sp2~sp11~sp22
```

Another dataset ("DIET.csv") indicates which species preying on other species (predator and prey):

```
     Predator       Prey       PreyMass       PredatorMass
1         sp1       sp10           45.5              125.5
2         sp1       sp11           22.4              125.5
3         sp2       sp10           45.5               84.0
4         sp2       sp12           22.1               84.0
5         sp3       sp22          178.0               60.0
```

I would like to: 1) identify all cells where each predator co-occurs with at least one of its prey; 2) identify cells for each predator where at least one another predator species preys on at least one similar prey.

I started with a code to turn the raw data into a matrix that lists which species occurs in each cell (a row for cell and a column for each animal):

```
spnames = read.csv("./Names of species in each cell.csv", as.is=TRUE) #Data

diet = read.csv("./DIET.csv", as.is=TRUE) #Data

M = matrix(nrow = nrow(spnames),ncol = nrow(diet))
for(i in 1:nrow(spnames))
{
    temp = strsplit(spnames$names[i],"~")

    #if there is at least one species there (length == 1 means there is 0 species)
    if(length(temp[[1]]) > 1)
    {
        #go through each species, and update the P/A matrix
        for(j in 2:length(temp[[1]]))
        {
            index = which(diet$Binom == temp[[1]][j])

            #Check to make sure exactly one species was matched
            if(length(index) == 1)
            {
                M[i,index] = 1
            } 
            else(print(paste("Error",i,j)))
        }
    }
}
```

Out of the matrix, eventually I would like to create raster layers for each predator species, with cells containing the two source of information mentioned above (available prey species for each predator species + predator species with similar prey for each predator species).

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define a *"similar"* prey?

Comment: if e.g. both sp1 and sp2 prey on sp10, so sp10 appears to be the prey for more than one predator @MarkSetchell

Comment: So "similar" = "same".

Comment: can some predators be preys for other predators?

Comment: Yes. There are 30 predators and more than 4000 prey species in total. @NicE